# What can I do about these discolored artifacts in viewport?

Tags: 3d-view, artifacts

The issue only started yesterday when I started a new project file, and the it doesn't seem to appear on my previous files. It doesn't appear on anything outside of Blender, just the new Blender files I make now. When I inserted an image as a background it resulted in the viewport having a bunch of weird colors:
[image]

Eventually, I found out that the smooth wiring in preferences was enabled so I turned that off and fixed that, but the issue still persists when I add new meshes.[image][image]
I am personally unsure if it's anything to worry about yet, nor do I understand what may be causing the issue.
For some specs I can provide: AMD Ryzen 5 5625U with Radeon Graphics, 8 GB RAM, and the entire thing itself is a Dell Inspiron 14 2-in-1 7425 Laptop. I haven't tested if it shows up in renders yet. I have updated, uninstalled and reinstalled Blender; as well as run diagnostics for the laptop, but I can't check the data either. I'm partially worried that if it is something wrong with the GPU, I currently don't have the opportunity to really fix it.

Comment: Looks like GPU issue

Comment: Yeah that’s a problem with your GPU 100%

Comment: Thank you for both of your answers! It turned out the GPU was outdated as a new update released today, so the update fixed the issue @Emir

Comment: and @Roger as well!